# Google Cloud Storage, blobstoreService, gzip compression

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have an appengine service to download files from cloud storage.
I go through appengine to handle specific access rights.
So I use the blobstoreService to serve the file :

```
blobstoreService.serve(blobstoreService.createGsBlobKey("bucket" + "filepath"))
```

I want to take advantage of the browsers decompression feature. So I set the metadata "Content-Encoding: gzip" on gziped files. But when I download my files through appengine, the metadata is not taken into account and the file is not decompressed.
If I use the cloud storage api, the header is set properly and the file is decompressed by the browser.

Is there a way to make it work with blobstoreService?

Comment: Not sure how you're "setting the metadata", buf if you pass a `HttpServletResponse` as the 2nd arg of `serve`, you shd be able to `.addHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip")` to it after the `serve` call -- did you try that?

Comment: Yes I did try it. This is what I do to set the Content-Type and it works, but only some headers are supported, If I set the Content-Encoding header, it's not taken into account and is removed by google.

    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
blobstoreService.serve(blobstoreService.createGsBlobKey("bucket" + "filepath"), httpServletResponse);

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem.  Looks like a bug in the GCS/GAE linkup perhaps

Answer (score 1):

I think Google Storage can't compress or decompress an object.
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers?csw=1#contentencoding

> Content-Encoding
>
> A request and response header that specifies the compression algorithm for an object.
>
> Valid Values: Any valid compression algorithm (see the specification).
>
> Example:  Content-Encoding: gzip
>
> **Details:    Cloud Storage does not compress or decompress objects.** If you use this header to specify a compression type algorithm (for example, deflate), Cloud Storage preserves the header but does not compress or decompress the object.

Comment: It would be better if you quote the relevant part of that document here, instead of giving just a link, because that link may become broken in the future.